# macOS SwiftUI: Instantiate new non-document window in document app

Tags: swiftui, macos-big-sur

Is there a pure-SwiftUI way to open a new window? I have a sorta-working document-based app whose app looks like this:

```swift
@main struct MyApp: App
{
    var
    body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: ProjectDocument.init) { inGroup in
            ProjectWindowContentView(document: inGroup.document)
                .frame(minWidth: 301.0, minHeight: 100.0)
                .onReceive(self.addTerrainGeneratorLayerCommand) { _ in
                    inGroup.document.addTerrainGeneratorLayer()
                }
        }
        .commands {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I want to add a menu command to instantiate a little self-contained utility tool in its own window. So far any discussion I see online actually involves making a new `NSWindow` with an `NSHostingView` as its content view. This seems not very SwiftUI-ish, and given their recent additions of `DocumentGroup` and `WindowGroup` seems like a pretty big oversight.

I tried putting a `WindowGroup` in the app’s scene, but it only shows my window if I comment out the `DocumentGroup`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need a `WindowGroup` for a window, so the first/simple step is just to add it, like

(Demo created with Xcode 12.5 / macOS 11.3, based on Document App template)

```
struct PlayDocumentXApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: PlayDocumentXDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
        WindowGroup("Tools") {
            Text("This is tool window")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 400)
        }
    }
}
```

and we have it available via `File > New` menu

[image: demo]

If we want to create/show it programmatically from other place, say via commands, we can use URL-based approach, like

[image: demo2]

```
struct PlayDocumentXApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: PlayDocumentXDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
        .commands {
            CommandMenu("Test") {
                Button("Show Tools") {
                    NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "myTools://my")!)
                }
            }
        }
        WindowGroup("Tools") {
            Text("This is tool window")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 400)
                .handlesExternalEvents(preferring: Set(arrayLiteral: "myTools://my"), allowing: Set(arrayLiteral: "myTools://my"))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: demo3]

Comment: I didn't realize it sticks a menu item for it in File->New. That'll do for now. The URL-based approach you describe sure seems like a workaround, but I guess it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the previous excellent answer, I came to this snippet.

- It shows how to add the command in the `Window` menu
- The syntax is a bit shorter ( handleExternalEvents(matching:) )

```swift
WindowGroup("Tools", id: "tools") {
    Text("This is tool window")
}
.commands {
    CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.windowList) {
        Button(action: {
            NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "myTools://my")!)
        }, label: {
            Text("Tool Window")
        })
    }
}
.handlesExternalEvents(matching: ["myTools://my"])
```