# Is it possible to use DocumentGroup in a SwiftUI iOS app along side WindowsGroup?

Tags: swiftui, documentgroup

I am developing an iOS app and want one separate view to manage document interaction. Is it possible to integrate DocumentGroup in my app that uses WindowGroup?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363964/12299030?