# Context environment to new window in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

for two days I try to solve the well known issue with

```
Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: ...>
```

in my app.

I tried nearly ever posted solution found on good old google - even I tried to understand Japanese sites. I've put the line

```
.environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
```

to nearly every line of code: either error or no result.

My problem: I like to open a new window and display a list of something (here: addresses). There must be a simple solution for that without rewriting and expanding parts of the framework. In my opinion this is not a very special thing so therefor apple might have an easy solution for that, I can't see.

My code so far:

XXXXApp.swift

```
    import SwiftUI

    @main  <<-- here: Context in environment is not connected to a persis....
    struct XXXXApp: App {
        let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
                    .navigationTitle("Buchliste")
            }
            WindowGroup("AddressBook") {
                AddressBookView()
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
                    .navigationTitle("Adressbuch")
            }.windowToolbarStyle(UnifiedCompactWindowToolbarStyle()).windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
            Settings {
                PreferencePane()
            }
        }
    }

    class WindowController<RootView: View>: NSWindowController {
        let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
        convenience init(rootView: RootView, width: Int, height: Int) {
            let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: rootView.frame(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))
            let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: hostingController)   <<-- here: Context in environment is not connected to a persis....
            window.setContentSize(NSSize(width: width, height: height))
            self.init(window: window)
        }
    }
```

snippet in ContextView.swift:

```
    ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
        Button {
              let windowController = WindowController(rootView: AddressBookView(), width: 800, height: 600 )
              windowController.window?.title = "Adressbuch"   <<-- here: Context in environment is not connected to a persis....
              windowController.showWindow(nil)
           } label: {
           Label("Adressbuch", systemImage: "book")
        }
    }
```

So, where is my mistake? Where do I have to put which code to make the app run properly?

Comment: Why do you create window that way? What's wrong with WindowGroup("AddressBook") ?

Comment: Cause I‘m a newbie to swift and this way I found worked for me. What would ve the right way?

Comment: I assume this should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363964/12299030

Comment: I tried it the way using URL Types. But then I get two other problems:
1. Opening by button opens the wrong view
2. opening by menu item, I get the right view (AddressBook) but the same error as above.

My goal: click button, oben „AddressBook“ View and see the data from database.

The tutorial I used was https://blog.rampatra.com/how-to-open-a-new-window-in-swiftui and it works so far, except showing the data, when opening the AddressBookView via button. Opening via menu item works with this solution pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HEUREKA!!

```
class WindowController<RootView: View>: NSWindowController {
    convenience init(rootView: RootView, width: Int, height: Int) {
        let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
        let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: rootView.frame(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)).environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext))
        let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: hostingController)
        window.setContentSize(NSSize(width: width, height: height))
        self.init(window: window)
    }
}
```

That's the right code for the WindowController. The environment-bla has to be added after frame as parameter. The persistenceController into the init and here we go!